# Difference between nvm node versions in nvm ls

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am trying to clean up my node installs, and `nvm ls` shows the following:

```
        v8.12.0
        v10.0.0
       v10.13.0
->       system
default -> lts/* (-> v10.13.0)
node -> stable (-> v10.13.0) (default)
stable -> 10.13 (-> v10.13.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> v10.13.0)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.4 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.12.0
lts/dubnium -> v10.13.0
```

What I actually need is only the latest LTS version, I would like to remove all the other ones.

`nvm uninstall lts/argon` or `nvm uninstall v4.9.1` returns:

> N/A version is not installed...

Question: What is the difference between the ones above **system** and below? What is "iojs"? How can I clean up this mess properly, in order to just have 1 node version (the latest LTS)?

Comment: is it possible that all those version (under -> system) were not installed using nvm?
If so, uninstall them from your system using the os tools. The other three (v8.12.0, v10.0.0, v10.13.0) look like they were installed using nvm, so "nvm uninstall v8.12.0" should work!

Comment: I think the `N/A` versions -like `iojs` - are not installed and for info that they exist remote.